# Incremental backups - differences

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

What is the differene between:

```
BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE;
```

and

```
BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 CUMULATIVE DATABASE;
```

I read some manuals, but I don't get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0` is a full backup of **all** used blocks in the database.
An `INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 CUMULATIVE` is a backup of **only the blocks that have changed** since the last incremental backup.

... the definitions above paraphrased from the Glossary of [Oracle Database Backup and Recovery User's Guide 11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/glossary.htm#i432786).

Answer (score 2):

`Incremental level 1 cummulative` is a backup only the blocks that have changed since the last incremental **0** backup

@George3 you should have mentioned  incremental level 0  not any incremental.